# Set RTL scroll direction for PDFView - Android

Tags: android, pdf, androidpdfviewer

I am using one Github library for view PDF file.
https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer

i want to set scroll direction RTL. please help to change scroll direction of this library.

I have tried solution from below link
https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-pdfview/issues/60

but its not worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I have found a hack. Rotate your pdf by 180 degress and then add following line in your code

```
pdf_activity_read_quraan.rotation = 180F
```

where is `pdf_activity_read_quraan` is reference of `com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView`

Comment: unknown Field "rotation" of ...PdfView
My code is : pdfview.rotation = 180F;

Comment: @BillelArfi use setRotation if you're using java

Comment: I use it but now the pages is upside down

Comment: @BillelArfi change your pdf by 180 also using some online software. and use rotation and not rotationx or rotationy

Comment: @BillelArfi Request you to upvote the answer if you find it useful

Answer (score 1):

**use onLoad method inside onCreate method like this:**

```
mypdfviewer.fromAsset("Quran.pdf").onLoad(new OnLoadCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void loadComplete(int nbPages) {
                mypdfviewer.fromAsset("Quran.pdf")
                        .pages(getPage(nbPages))
                        .defaultPage(nbPages)
                        .enableSwipe(true)
                        .enableDoubletap(true)
                        .swipeHorizontal(true)
                        .password(null).enableAntialiasing ( true ).spacing(0)
                        .pageSnap(true).pageFling(true)
                        .autoSpacing ( false ).pageFitPolicy ( FitPolicy. WIDTH ).fitEachPage ( true )
                        .scrollHandle(new DefaultScrollHandle(null))
                        .load();

            }
        }).load();
```

**create getPage method **

```
 private int [] getPage(int nbPages) {
    int [] pages =new int[nbPages];
    int j=0;
    for(int i=pages.length-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        pages[j]=i;
        j++;
    }
    return  pages;
}
```

**working for me:)**

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `android:supportsRtl="true"` in `Application` tag of the manifest file.

Source : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html

---

Possible workaround would be acquiring the scroll and force move like this :

```
mScrollView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        scrollView.fullScroll(HorizontalScrollView.FOCUS_RIGHT); // or scrollTo
    }
}, 100L);
```

Comment: I am using below class for display PDF and scroll managed dynamically.

https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer/blob/master/android-pdf-viewer/src/main/java/com/github/barteksc/pdfviewer/PDFView.java