# Set RTL scroll on AndroidPdfViewer

Tags: android, androidpdfviewer

I use this lib https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer

I want on horizontal scroll .scroll RTL because I read Arabic book
I see this and it's not work
[Set RTL scroll direction for PDFView - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43183645/set-rtl-scroll-direction-for-pdfview-android)
I hope you will be  help me